# Typescript Prisma style conditional return type not working as expected

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, prisma

I am trying to create a custom conditional type much like Prisma's types which return a different type based on the properties inside the input parameter to a function.

My simplified code looks like this:

```js
type Group = {};
type User = {};

type ResolveQueryOptions = {
  user: boolean;
  group: boolean;
};

const defaultResolveQueryOptions: ResolveQueryOptions = {
  group: true,
  user: false,
};

type SelectKeys<T extends ResolveQueryOptions> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends false ? never : K]: K;
};

type StringToType<
  S extends ResolveQueryOptions,
  T extends SelectKeys<S>
> = T extends 'group' ? Group : T extends 'user' ? User : never;

type QueryResult<T extends ResolveQueryOptions> = {
  result: {
    [K in SelectKeys<T>]: StringToType<T, K>[];
  };
};

function example<T extends ResolveQueryOptions>(options: T): QueryResult<T> {
  const a: any = {};

  if (options.group) {
    a.result.group = [] as Group[];
  }
  if (options.user) {
    a.result.user = [] as User[];
  }

  return a as QueryResult<T>;
}

const result = example(defaultResolveQueryOptions);

result.result.group;
result.result.user; // I expect this to be undefined and give a TS error, however it doesn't
```

According to some articles ([this](https://pkerschbaum.com/blog/how-prisma-adapts-result-types-based-on-the-actual-arguments-given) and [this](https://dev.to/zenstack/dynamic-return-type-based-on-input-parameter-in-typescript-like-prisma-1292)) that I found related to this topic it should work like this:
By extending the type in the function (`<T extends ResolveQueryOptions>`), but not specifying it when calling the function (`const result = example(defaultResolveQueryOptions);`) Typescript should resolve the type from the input parameter (`options T`).

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the answer and would like to add it here if anyone else runs into this issue at some point.
The problem was that my `defaultResolveQueryOptions` had a type specified (`: ResolveQueryOptions`) and Typescript then chooses to use this type, instead of inferring the type based on the value.

Changing that declaration from:

```js
const defaultResolveQueryOptions: ResolveQueryOptions = {
  group: true,
  user: false,
};
```

To

```js
const defaultResolveQueryOptions = {
  group: true,
  user: false,
} as const;
```

Fixes the problem!